# Player animation don't trigger if bool changed from value

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm following the [Player Character tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144) on the Unity site. There say that the player can move, idle or can be dead. Here is the situation in the 'Animator' panel:

[image]

The parameters are:

- `IsWalking` type of bool
- `Die` type of trigger

The normal situation is when the `IsWalking` parameters is true, he must begin whit walking. When false, he must stop. Here are some screenshots.

[image]

And here is the C# script I've made:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.

    Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
    Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
    int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
    float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.

    void Awake()
    {
        // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");

        // Set up references.
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Store the input axes.
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        // Move the player around the scene.
        Move(h, v);

        // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
        Turning();

        // Animate the player.
        Animating(h, v);
    }

    void Move(float h, float v)
    {
        // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

        // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning()
    {
        // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
        if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
        {
            // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

            // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);

            // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }
    }

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        // Create a boolean that is true if either of the input axes is non-zero.
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;

        // Tell the animator whether or not the player is walking.
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

The problem is now, when I'll walk whit the player he stays in the idle state. It's sometimes that he goes to the move state, but not always. What is the problem here I've got? I've exactly the same code and animations I've made in the animator and inspector tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting ExitTime to false.

When on, it means the animation will still be played by the ExitTime value. So for instance if ExitTime is 1, the whole idle animation has to be finished before it transits. If you stop moving within that time, then the boolean is back to idle and you won't see the animation for walking. Setting it to false means you want transition to happen instantly.